# Easygui module not found after compilation

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to compile python code with cython. The python code has easygui module:

```
from easygui import *
```

The commands used are:

```
cython --embed myfile.py
gcc -I/usr/include/python3.5m -lpython3.5m myfile.c -o myfile.x
```

The process runs without any message or error but when I run myfile.x, I get following error message:

```
$ ./myfile.x 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 6, in init myfile
    from easygui import *
ImportError: No module named 'easygui'
```

I am working on Debian Stable Linux.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that Cython embed doesn't set the Python path. You might try setting it using an environmental variable when you start your program (but that isn't really a great long-term solution)

Comment: I tried `cython --embed -I/usr/include/python3.5m myfile.py` but it still gives same error. I searched for files in `/usr` folder and found following related to easygui: `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/easygui.py` , `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/__pycache__/easygui.cpython-35.pyc` and `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/easygui-0.96.egg-info`. There are also files in `/usr/share/doc/python3-easygui` folder.

Comment: No - I don't mean the include path for gcc. I mean the module search path at runtime https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: When I test it I don't have your problem (so can't be too helpful) but I needed to correct your gcc line: `gcc myfile.c -o myfile.x -I/usr/include/python3.5m -lpython3.5m`. Note the change in file extension and command line order.

Comment: It was a typing error: should be .c and not .py in gcc command. I have corrected it in question above.

Comment: I am looking at my sys.path. It is ['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-i386-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']. And easygui.py is in /usr/lib/python3/dst-packages (as I mentioned above). So why it is not being found?

Comment: If you print `sys.path` in your executable is it the same as when you print it in Python?

Comment: That gets the problem! This folder was on a different partition than the main linux partition. The executable is looking for paths on that partition. When I run the same executable on main partition, it works. You should put your suggestions as an answer. Also, is there any way to include all required modules in the executable?

Comment: How can I use `pyximport.install(pyimport = True)` as mentioned on http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html to compile all modules that are being imported ?

Comment: It might be easier for you to post the answer yourself. I'm not sure I know _exactly_ what was wrong on your specific system. I don't think it is possible to include all the required modules in the executable - pyinstaller or cx_freeze try to do this I think, but I haven't used either. If you want to use `pyximport.install(pyimport=True)` then put it as the first line of your script and it should just work I think.

Comment: It is not finding `pyximport` module. That module is not there in pip or in Debian repositories.

Comment: This is my last comment on this, but: I think `pyximport` is part of Cython. The package you have to install is probably called `cython3` to be able to import Cython in Python 3. (For the purpose of compiling .pyx files it doesn't matter if you're using Cython for Python 2 or 3, but to import it it does)

Comment: It works with cython3 but hangs - seems to be taking a long time working on many modules. I stopped it with control-c.